# How to post data with null fields in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to have a source class that takes in either a project, profile, department, or team as
an AutoOneToOne Field from django_annoying. Basically, I am trying to have access to the sourceID and source type (project, profile, department, or team) to then send to a different class: Posts. When I try to add a source with profile "s" and null for the other fields as shown here:

[image: Adding a source with profile 's' and null for the other fields]

I get the following error message:

[image: error message]

I've tried adding a default="", but that is counterintuitive, and doesn't work anyways. Here is my Source class:

```
class Source(models.Model):
    profile = AutoOneToOneField('Profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    project= models.OneToOneField('Project', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    team = AutoOneToOneField('Team', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    department = AutoOneToOneField('Department', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.profile + self.project + self.team + self.department
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies in the `Source` models `__str__()` method where you're attempting to add together all of its fields, but they are not strings, and cannot be concatenated. You could cast each of them to a string first, but based on your model description three of the four fields will be `None`'s.

If you want to select the only non-null field in `Source` and return its string representation:

```py
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.profile or self.project or self.team or self.department)
```

If you want to reuse the same selection criteria for other purposes you could first add it as a custom property to the model:

```py
@property
def obj(self):
    return self.profile or self.project or self.team or self.department

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.obj)
```

And then you can access the only non-null field as an attribute of any `Source` object, for example, to get its ID or type (as you mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I used more than 1 plus sign in the def **str**, so to fix this, all I did was switch it to this:

```
def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Comment: The issue wasn't the number of plus signs. The issue was trying to concatenate non-strings. I think what you might have been looking for was `return str(self.profile or self.project or self.team or self.department)`. Based on your description, only one of the options is non-null, so the `or` conditions would return the non-null option and then cast it to a `str`.

Comment: If you'd like to post this as answer, I'll accept it! Thanks @elyas